# Error "WinVerifyTrust failed with hrc=Unknown Status" when launching a guest machine on VirtualBox

Tags: windows-8.1, virtualbox, virtual-machine

After working flawlessly for months, all of a sudden I cannot launch guests on VirtualBox. When I attempt to launch a VM, I receive the error:

> WinVerifyTrust failed on stub executable: WinVerifyTrust failed with hrc=Unknown Status 0x8009200D on '\Device\HarddiskVolumeX\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VirtualBox.exe' (rc=-22919)
>   Please try reinstalling VirtualBox.

I've uninstalled and reinstalled VirtualBox (5.0.0.r101573), and also deleted and re-imported my OVA Appliance, but am still receiving this error.

Any ideas?

**Edit**

From this [post here](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=74631), seemingly Windows Security Update KB3081320 breaks VB.

I've confirmed that after removing KB3081320 via

```
wusa /uninstall /kb:3081320
```

and rebooting, that I can load the VM again. However I do not feel comfortable with this workaround as security is now potentially compromised.

Comment: related : http://superuser.com/questions/942036/virtualbox-fails-to-start-on-windows-server-2003

Comment: You are not using the current version of VirtualBox this problem can be solved by simply, by installing the current version of VirtualBox, you don't have to uninstall the related security update.

Comment: Thanks @BlueBerry-Vignesh4303 and RamHound - I'll download the latest version of VirtualBox overnight and let you know.

Comment: install VB 5.0.10: https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found that installing the new Virtual box from https://www.virtualbox.org/ fixed mine , version 5.0.10, i think it has to do with the windows 8.1 windows update

Comment: updating to the latest vbox version resolved this issue for me.

Comment: Thanks - after a couple of days, Windows will reinstall `KB3081320` again breaking VB. Upgrading to VB 5.0.10 was trivial, and all the existing machines and configurations were all retained.

Comment: BTW, looks like installing a recent Windows 10 like the ones from the "Insider Preview" program will break VirtualBox - I could not find any fix.